# Why use get_absolute_url function not work?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to use get_absolute_url to get an object (post_detail) from (post_list),
but returns with no object and still in the same page (post_list) with no error.
in `views.py` :

**# Object list using Function-based-views**

```
def post_list(request):
    post_list=Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    lastest=post_list.order_by('-created_at')[:4]
    last_post= post_list.order_by('-created_at')[0]
    context={
        'allpost':post_list,
        'latest':lastest,
        'lastpost':last_post
    }
    return render(request,'post/post_list.html',context)
```

**# Post_singl_object using DetailView**

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model=Post
    context_object_name='post_detail'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context= super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['slug']=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

urls.py :

from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name="allpost"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list),
    path('<slug:slug>',views.PostDetail.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
]
```

in my templates in page (post_list.html) i loop for list objects to get (title,headline, image, and author), but in a link i use (

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={'slug': self.slug}
```

) to redirect to post page, but that's not work and still in same page (post_list).
in `post_list.html` :

```
{% for post in allpost  %}
<a href="{{ post_detail.get_absolute_url }}" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>

{% endfor %}
```

any idea ?

Comment: You wrote `href="{{ post_detail.get_absolute_url }}"` **post_detail** is not the object. Instead, `href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"`

Comment: i changed it (post instead post_detail), but return with error: **Reverse for 'post_detail' not found. 'post_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

Answer (score 0):

**You forgot to preced the url by the app_name label defined in the `urls.py` file**

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("allpost:post_detail", kwargs={'slug': self.slug}
```

Comment: thanks, but it not works, it still in same page (post_list)

Comment: what is the content of the link when you hover the `button` ? (bottom left on chrome browser)

Comment: it just shows this: 27.0.0.1:8000/blog/